# Flutterfragment does not get ChangeNotifier updates

Tags: android, flutter, fragment, flutter-getx

I am using FlutterFragment to host a flutter fragment inside the android studio. That's it, flutter opens an android activity (map screen) that in turns hosts a FlutterFragment (a simple Bottomsheet). The problem is that when I update the change something inside the ChangeNotifier androidNavigationController, it does not reflect inside the AndroidCustomNavigationBottomSheet. Besides, any thing inside the AndroidCustomNavigationBottomSheet can not get any updates from any GetxController. Any idea what might be the problem? I wonder if it is something about create a new engine other than the FlutterEngine? This is parts of the code:

```
 GetMaterialApp(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
                    return MediaQuery(
                      data:  data.copyWith(textScaleFactor: data.textScaleFactor.clamp(0.5, 3.2)),
                      child: child!
                    );
                  },
                  title: '$appName',
                  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  theme: MyTheme.darkTheme,
                  darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme,
                  themeMode:  ThemeMode.dark,
                  routes: {
                    LoginScreen.routeName:            (context) => LoginScreen(),
                    HomeScreen.routeName:             (context) => HomeScreen(),
                    LoginWithCredentials.routeName:   (context) => LoginWithCredentials(),
**                    'flutter_android_bottomsheet':    (context) => Provider.value(value: androidNavigationController, child: AndroidCustomNavigationBottomSheet(),)**
                  },
                  getPages: [
                    GetPage(name: HomeScreen.routeName, page: () => HomeScreen())
                  ],
                  translations: MyTranslation(),
                  locale: translationController.initialLang,
                  home: Home(isDark)
            );
```

Inside my MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
...

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        globalFlutterEngine = flutterEngine

        mainViewBinding = MainViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mainViewBinding.root)

        ...

        val newEngine = FlutterEngine(this)
        newEngine.navigationChannel.setInitialRoute("flutter_android_bottomsheet")
        newEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        )
        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put("my_cached_engine", newEngine)
    }
```

And inside my NavigationActivity

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = NavigationActivityWithTokenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        flutterFragment = FlutterFragment.withCachedEngine("my_cached_engine").transparencyMode(TransparencyMode.transparent).build()
        val tx: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        tx.replace(R.id.flutter_container, flutterFragment!!)
        tx.commitNow()
        supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()

}
}
```

Tried and expected: Used FluterFragment (a AndroidCustomNavigationBottomSheet Flutter widget) that is host by an Android activity and expected the FluterFragment to use other ChangeNotifier and Getxcontroller objects.
Result: AndroidCustomNavigationBottomSheet Flutter widget is not getting any updates from ChangeNotifier nor Getxcontroller.